# PHP - Large file upload error

Tags: php, actionscript-3, file-upload

I'm sending from a AIR desktop application an image along with some text as a Base64 encoded string. 
If the image size is around 100 KB the upload works but if its a bigger one ~220 KB I get an Error thrown back after some time.

The error tells ***http://www.example.com/upload.php - Error opening URL*** but the url path is correct and can be found.

What is wrong with my PHP?

```
<?php
$file         = $_POST["thefile"];         
$text_message = $_POST["themessage"];       
$subject      = $_POST["thesubject"];        
$from         = $_POST["thesender"];        
$to           = $_POST["theaddress"];                 

    $attachment=uniqid(rand(), true) . '.png';

   $headers="From: $from\r\n";
    $headers.="Reply-to: $from\r\n";
    $headers.="Return-Path: $from\r\n";

    if (isset($_ENV["SERVER_NAME"])) 
        $headers.="Message-Id: <" . md5(uniqid(microtime())) . "@" . $_ENV["SERVER_NAME"] . ">\r\n";
    else
        $headers.="Message-Id: <" . md5(uniqid(microtime())) . "@" . 'unknown' . ">\r\n";
    $headers.="Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n";
    $headers.="X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
    if (isset($_ENV["REMOTE_ADDR"])) 
        $headers.="X-SenderIP: " . $_ENV["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "\r\n";
    else
        $headers.="X-SenderIP: " . 'unknown' . "\r\n";
    if (isset($_ENV["SERVER_NAME"])) 
        $headers.="X-WebSite: " . $_ENV["SERVER_NAME"] . "\r\n";
    else
        $headers.="X-WebSite: " . 'unknown' . "\r\n";
    $headers.="X-Script: SWF_Generator\r\n";
    $bound_text=md5(uniqid(time()));

        $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$bound_text\"\r\n";
        $message="--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"      
                ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"  
                ."<html><head></head><body>"
                ."<div style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 1.3em; color: #000000;width: 100%;text-align: left;\">$text_message</div></body></html>\r\n\r\n"  
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"  
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment\"\r\n"
                ."Content-Type: image/png; name=\"$attachment\"\r\n\r\n"
        .chunk_split($file)
        ."\r\n\r\n"
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text--\r\n\r\n";

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

Server informations:

```
PHP Version 5.2.12-nmm2 System  

 Debug Build:   no  
Thread Safety:  disabled  
Zend Memory Manager:    enabled

Registered PHP Streams:     https, ftps,
 compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, data, http, ftp, zip 
 Registered Stream Socket Transports:   tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3,
 sslv2, tls  
Registered Stream Filters:  zlib.*, bzip2.*,
 convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower,
 string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed
```

Comment: I would disable the mail function first and see if that fixes it. you might be running into something funky with the mail

Comment: Just tried that but nothing changed. The same error comes up.

Answer (score 1):

check out upload_max_filesize and post_max_size from phpinfo(). They usually are in megabytes but check anyway. post_max_size should be twice the size of the largest file uploaded.

Check out server logs for the php error.

Comment: Please add the manual link. And I don't think you're correct about the "twice the size".

Comment: From my phpinfo(): `max_execution_time 800 30 |
max_file_uploads 20 20 |
max_input_nesting_level 64 64 |
max_input_time 100 60 |
memory_limit 120M 64M` - Should that be enough for uploading a ~230 KB image? (230 KB image encoded as a Base64 string)

Comment: These are not the droids we're looking for. Check for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.  The Post size should be bigger than upload maximum filesize as the data is encoded depending on form settings. Usually post size is ~ 1.7 binary size.

Comment: Here are the values: upload_max_filesize: local: 100M / master: 200M || post_max_size: local: 100M / master: 200M | Are the values high enough?

Comment: So here are my server logs for today: `Mon Nov 07 18:02:19 2011 0 ::ffff:75.99.149.1 2545 /www/htdocs/abcde123/send/upload.php a _ i r example.com ftps 0 * c
Mon Nov 07 22:11:59 2011 0 ::ffff:75.99.149.1 2545 /www/htdocs/abcde123/.htaccess a _ o r example.com ftps 0 * c
` I don't know what they are telling me. Somebody sees an answer in there for my upload error problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use amfphp or send post data method ?
Your way with Base64 is for sure slower and require server processing , You can avoid it.

link to post method :
http://www.neerfri.com/2007/12/flex-multipartform-data-post-request.html